# converting date to the correct time zone

Tags: java, time, timezone, date-conversion

I'm scraping some data for a user, part of it is a date in a Unix Timestamp:

[image]

The user is living in London and wants to see the date for his specific time zone. As you can see, on GMT it is 6/21, on my time zone (Israel Time Zone) it's 6/22.

I used this snippet code to fix:

```
            private SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            txnDate = "1529618400000" //this is hardcoded, just for the example
            txnDateValue = new Date(Long.valueOf(txnDate));
            TimeZone london = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London");
            sdf2.setTimeZone(london);
            txnDate = sdf2.format(txnDateValue);
```

So that the date will be converted to the correct time zone (London in his case).

It still doesn't work for him - he claims that he sees the date in one day difference.

What could go wrong here?

Comment: which is the `txnDateValue` passed ?

Comment: why not use `ZonedDateTime` instead in java 8 and above

Comment: If you cannot, refer to this tutorial: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/java-util-timezone.html

Comment: What is the default time zone of the JVM where the program is running? (You may want to print the output from `TimeZone.getDefault()` or `ZoneId.systemDefault()`.)

Comment: I cannot readily reproduce. When I set my JVM’s time zone to `Asia/Tel_Aviv` and run your code, I get a `txnDateValue` of `Fri Jun 22 01:00:00 IDT 2018` and a `txnDate` of `2018-06-21`, which I understood was what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

> What could go wrong here?

- The Date obtained and stored in txnDateValue could have been read wrong, with bad time zone or bad format or whatever
- The DateFormat built and stored in sdf2 could be badly made or badly used, with bad pattern or concurrent use or whatever.

Bottomline, you should design complete programs to test the input/output on your side and your partner's side, and if that's not enough to help you find the problem, you should show us this complete programs.

Code snippets are useless. We don't have problems, you do. If we use code snippets you provide, we won't have problems with them. You're the one who have problems with them. So, there is no sense showing anything but a complete program we can run as-is.

Comment: Hi, I added more information... maybe the case is more clear now?

Comment: If the `Date` comes from parsing a long and passing it to the `Date(long)` constructor, I see nothing going wrong there (save confusing seconds and milliseconds, but I doubt it is what is happening here). Concurrent use of the `SimpleDateFormat` is a possible explanation. In this case the error should not be reproducible always. (I know your answer was posted before the edit of the question, so you didn’t have the information I and we have now.)

Answer (score 0):

### Modern version: use java.time

```
        Instant txnDateValue = Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.parseLong(txnDate));
        ZoneId london = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");
        txnDate = txnDateValue.atZone(london).format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
```

The above gives an `Instant` of `2018-06-21T22:00:00Z` (where `Z` means UTC) and a `txnDate` of `2018-06-21`. Like you own code it is not thread-safe if some other thread may manipulate `txnDate` or some other variable involved.

### What went wrong in your code?

I cannot tell. Kumesana suggested a race condition, like concurrent use of your `SimpleDateFormat`, this is a possibility. Other possibilities are that your program isn’t working on the data you think or your user in London made a mistake. Apart from these conditions I believe that your program should produce `2018-06-21`.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time` including the classes `Instant`, `ZoneId` and `DateTimeFormatter` that I used in my code.